# Get filename/path from NSItemProvider

Tags: macos, share-extension, nsitemprovider

My share extension for macOS takes image or video files.

I'd like to be able to access the filename (or path) for the `NSItemProvider` object.

I've figured I can use `itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation()` to get the data for the media. However its not clear to me how to retrieve the filename/path.

When I print the itemProvider object, I get this:

```
<NSItemProvider: 0x600002998d20> {types = (
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.file-url",
    "public.url"
)}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

```
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeURL as String, options: nil, completionHandler: {
                        (data, error) in
                        if let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data as! Data, relativeTo: nil){
                            let filename = url.lastPathComponent
                            print(filename)
                        }
                    })
```